# Why use cyclotomic polynomials for RLWE?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, lwe, ring-lwe

This paper [On Ideal Lattices and Learning with Errors Over Rings](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/230) proposed RLWE which is Ring and hence efficient version of LWE problem.  My question is that they considered cyclotomic polynomials for modulus. I am not sure why cyclotomic polynomials are used and what extra advantage we get by using them?

Comment: There was a question about this few days ago. [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100211/rlwe-explanation/100218#100218) may be helpful.

Comment: Could you please indicate in how far the linked to Q/A is helpful? Please indicate what is missing, otherwise this question may get closed as a duplicate.